# Parsing in Java works but in Android it shows error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name must not be empty

Tags: java, android, header, http-headers, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a redirected page from an HTML page and it works just fine when I'm trying to run it in Java console but some how it fails when I'm trying to run the same code in Android.

Here's the stack:

```
W: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name must not be empty
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Base.header(HttpConnection.java:292)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.processResponseHeaders(HttpConnection.java:828)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.setupFromConnection(HttpConnection.java:772)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:569)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
    W:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
    W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.getGradesList(GradesParser.java:48)
    W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.doInBackground(GradesParser.java:32)
    W:     at gavi_anna_netanel.com.madomes.ug_login.GradesParser$GradesFetcher.doInBackground(GradesParser.java:28)
    W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Anna on 6/18/2016.
 */
public class GradesParser {

    String outputFileName;

    public GradesParser(String outputFileName) {
        this.outputFileName = outputFileName;
    }

    private class GradesFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getGradesList(params[0], params[1]);
        }

        private Document getGradesList(String username, String password) {
            try {
                //create session (?) and prepare initial cookie
                Response resp1 = Jsoup.connect("http://techmvs.technion.ac.il/cics/wmn/wmngrad?ORD=1").followRedirects(true).execute();
                String url1 = resp1.url().toString();
                Map welcomeCookies = resp1.cookies();
                //login for the session
                String url2 = url1 + "&s=1";
                Response resp2 = Jsoup
                        .connect(url1 + "&s=1")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .data("userid", username)
                        .data("password", password)
                        .data("function", "signon")
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .header("Referer", "http://ug3.technion.ac.il/Tadpis.html")
                        .cookies(welcomeCookies)
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .execute();


                Map<String, String> coockies = resp2.cookies();
                if ((!coockies.containsKey("TechAnamUser")) || (coockies.get("TechAnamUser") != username)) {
                    return null;
                }

                Document doc3 = Jsoup.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(resp2.bodyAsBytes()), "ISO-8859-8", url2);
                return doc3;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public JSONObject gradesParse(String username, String password) {
        Document gradesList = null;
        try {
            gradesList = new GradesFetcher().execute(username, password).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        if (gradesList == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Elements tables = gradesList.getElementsByTag("table");
        Elements rows = tables.get(2).select("tr");
        Elements cells = rows.get(1).select("td");
        JSONObject gradesListObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            gradesListObject.put("point num", Float.parseFloat(cells.get(0).text()));
            gradesListObject.put("success rate", Integer.parseInt(cells.get(1).text()));
            gradesListObject.put("average", Float.parseFloat(cells.get(2).text()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        JSONArray semesters = new JSONArray();
        if (tables.size() > 5) {
            for (int i = 4; i < tables.size() - 1; i++) {
                JSONObject semester = new JSONObject();
                rows = tables.get(i).select("tr");
                JSONArray courses = new JSONArray();
                for (int j = 2; j < rows.size() - 1; j++) {
                    JSONObject course = new JSONObject();
                    cells = rows.get(j).select("td");
                    try {
                        course.put("grade", Integer.parseInt(cells.get(0).text()));
                        course.put("points", Float.parseFloat(cells.get(1).text()));
                        String numberWithName = cells.get(2).text();
                        numberWithName = numberWithName.replace("\u00a0", " ");
                        String[] splitted = numberWithName.split(" ");
                        String name = new StringBuilder(splitted[splitted.length - 2]).reverse().toString();
                        for (int k = splitted.length - 3; k >= 0; k--) {
                            name = name + " " + new StringBuilder(splitted[k]).reverse().toString();
                        }
                        course.put("number", splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
                        course.put("name", name);
                        courses.put(course);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    semester.put("courses", (Object) courses);
                    Element lastRow = rows.get(rows.size() - 1);
                    cells = lastRow.select("td");
                    semester.put("points", Float.parseFloat(cells.get(1).text()));
                    String averageWithSuccessRate = cells.get(0).text();
                    averageWithSuccessRate = averageWithSuccessRate.replace("\u00a0", " ");
                    String[] separeted = averageWithSuccessRate.split(" ");
                    semester.put("average", Float.parseFloat(separeted[0]));
                    semester.put("success rate", Integer.parseInt(separeted[2].substring(0, separeted[2].length() - 1)));
                    semesters.put(semester);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            gradesListObject.put("semesters", (Object) semesters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return gradesListObject;
    }


}
```

I may have little understanding of the header I need, but I have tried several and couldn't find it. I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Where I declare resp1

Comment: Try adding the missing headers to it, perhaps

Comment: I'm not sure which headers I should add.... That's the reason I wrote the question

Comment: Nobody except the guys who manage that server can tell you that. I would recommend duplicating the headers made by your browser, and removing them until you're down to the bare-minimum.

Comment: It seems like the server guy posted some junk characters in order to confuse these kinds of parsing and make it believe it has an empty header. Is there any way for a workaround?

Comment: Try to add the `userAgent` string to all of your requests. Different agents may get different replies from some servers. If your code works on some OS both not on others, this may be the cause.

Comment: Our team decided to manipulate the jsoup files to ignore such header. This worked for us.

Answer (score -1):

Solution chosen by OP:

> Our team decided to manipulate the jsoup files to ignore such header. This worked for us.